# Debian wired connection static IP wont connect

Tags: linux, debian, networking, ethernet

I've installed Debian with xfce and did some configuring by installing themes, configuring xfce, installing and uninstalling software; the usual. Anyway, after a reboot I can't connect to the internet. I can't connect with chrome and ping doesn't return anything with DNS or IP. This happened with a previous installation and I assumed it was an installation error so I re-installed and configured my system again and the same thing happened. The system does not have wireless, the ethernet is the only networking resource. I've tested the line on my laptop and it works, the internet is also fine. THis wasn't an issue until I recently rebooted. I've also had a problem with xorg. It doens't start when I boot, I have to type "startx" to get a gui. All signs that I can observe point toward this being a machine-problem

$ ip link

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mod DEFAULT
  link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
  link/ehter 44:8a:5b:9f:bd:cb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

$ cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

"
$ auto eth0
$ allow-hotplug eth0
$ iface eth0 inet dhcp
"
All return "bash: *: command not found"

$ ping -c 3 www.google.com

```
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

$ ping -c 3 8.8.8.8

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

Comment: Did you uninstall `network-manager` by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following two lines to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Then, as `root`, run

```
ifup eth0
```

You can probably fix your X.org problem by installing `lightdm`; that will start a desktop manager when the system boots.

Comment: I believe they're in there.. his text formatting is just really messed p